# SSRS, some fields are not displayed report once deployed to server (Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008

I am not able to view some of the fields once the report is generated on server. Report is getting generated properly but data is not being displyed. The report works fine on local machine.

Below is the screenshot of the issue I am facing.

Local Reports:

[image: Locally Working Screenshot]

On Server I am facing the issue as below, the data is fetched properly as can be seen on the screenshot. The sections have got created correctly indicates query has executed successfuly. For some strange reasons only `Time` column is getting displayed.

[image: Issue on server]

Comment: All data coming from database only? if yes, are you using a separate user account from the SharePoint than the one you use in your local env?

Comment: @Kangkan separate user account from the SharePoint than the one you use in your local env? local server has different set of users so yes a different user and also the report is deployed on ii7. i did changes as mentioned in below link but that dint work. http://www.briteglobal.com/en/blogs/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=15

Comment: @Kangkan i had deployed the reports on another test server (ii7), it works fine there.

Comment: Do the users have access to the database to retrieve all the data? Is there something in the server log?

Comment: Yes the user has all the rights. I have sorted out the issue, will post as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue was because Dataset did not contain all the columns, i changed the default view and added all the fields to the default view.

I could see only time column as the default view had only `Time` column in it, i had to add all other columns in order to get it working.

Referred [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/332ce140-1e8b-4e69-b29c-60f516caf5cd/) link to get to the solution.